# Magento admin login redirects to Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

After I login to the magento admin panel I am redirected to the `Magento Extension Manager` login screen.

Once I login to the `magento extension manager` I am not able to reach the admin panel despite clicking on the `Return to Admin` link.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the text "`%startup%`" in `core_config_data` table in the column `path` and change the value to "`dashboard`" or delete the row.